# How to handle HtmlDocument null exception

Tags: c#

I am checking a HtmlDocument() by html id called `shippingMessage_ftinfo_olp_1` but problem is that i am unable to check if this is a null exception. Because when i set if `!=null` still it throws exception. Anyone can tell me how can i check it if its null without this exception?

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(response);
string gerLang = "";
if (htmlDoc.GetElementbyId("shippingMessage_ftinfo_olp_1").InnerText != null)
{
    gerLang = htmlDoc.GetElementbyId("shippingMessage_ftinfo_olp_1").InnerText;
    if(gerLang.Contains("AmazonGlobal Express-Zustellung"))
    {
        _outOfStock = false;
    }
}
```

[image: pic]

Comment: you messed up the title -> Cocument

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Someone will be along soon to close this out as a duplicate of the question I've linked. However, you want to check that `htmlDoc.GetElementbyId("shippingMessage_ftinfo_olp_1") != null` before you check the `InnerText`.

Comment: When someone dont know the solution, its a way to mark as duplicate with a source manual book! Good job but the great guy not hesitate to answer as i selected bellow

Comment: I also voted your question as a duplicate of that question, but provided an answer as a community wiki answer to help you solve your exact problem :-) (not to say that Kirk didn't also provide a solution above).

Comment: Real solution is so quick just put `?` anywhere you dont trust! haha thanks to mark as duplicate also!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators):

```
if (htmlDoc.GetElementbyId("shippingMessage_ftinfo_olp_1")?.InnerText != null)
```

If `htmlDoc` can be null, also change that to `htmlDoc?.GetEle....`

Reasoning: A null conditional operator short-circuits the evaluation if the object being evaluated is null, preventing you from getting an exception, in favour of evaluating to null.

Comment: I learned new one from you! great answer man! Thanks. Works like charm